# Bank Details On Success Page of Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, payment-methods, order-success-page, payment-banktransfer

If the **payment method** is **bank transfer**, I need to show a **custom message on success page** of Magento 2.

I'm going to say

> "don't forget: we will ship to you after your payment received to our
>   bank account; here are our bank details; and you have 2 days left to
>   make your payment"

etc..

I found the solution as like below (with editing success.phtml), but you know, I don't want to edit core files.

```
<?php if ($this->getOrderId()):?>
<div class="bank_detail">
<?php $orderId = $this->getOrderId(); ?>
<?php $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->loadByIncrementId($orderId); //load order by increment id?>
<?php $paymentCode = $order->getPayment()->getMethod(); ?>

   <?php if ($paymentCode=='banktransfer') { 
       echo "whatever you want!";
   } //you can also check for other payment method?>
```

Could someone help me to do this with the module?

Comment: You can try by 'order.success.additional.info'

Comment: it is possible by creating one simple module and call you custom phtml file on the success page.

Comment: @erererer please check my answer and let me know It will help you.

Comment: No need to create any custom module. You can simply create a widget from the admin panel and call it on the checkout success page.

Comment: could someone help me to modify success.phtml or create custom_info.phtml? i need to say 'if payment method=banktransfer, echo xxxx' etc

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create the new module, you can do it in your theme as well. Follow below steps:

Create `checkout_onepage_success.xml` in your theme.

For example:

> app/design/frontend/Package/Theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_onepage_success.xml.

The content of file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="order.success.additional.info">
        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success"
               name="custom_info.order.success"
               template="Magento_Checkout::order/success/custom_info.phtml"
               after="-">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Then you need to create the template file:

> app/design/frontend/Package/Theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/order/success/custom_info.phtml.

You can add your conditional code to this file.

**For example:**

*My bank information is xyz*

**Run:**

> php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: thank you so so much for your kind answer.. but, could you please show me a way with a creating new module? (i need to write bank details, IF payment method is bank transfer)

Comment: you can create a system configuration field and add your data to this field and call it on 'custom_info.phtml' it will done :)

Comment: if any answer solves your concern then there is green right tick mark , hit that tickmark for right ansewer that will help future readers.

Comment: May i also please you to give an custom_info.phtml example? if paymentmethod=bank transfer) { echo 'bank details: xxxx'; } etc..